# next.js: static generation with dynamic path segment

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel

**Baseline**

I understand the general concepts of dynamic routing and of static generation.

I am also aware of the solutions to statically pre-generate pages if they contain dynamic path segments as shown [here](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/dynamic-routes/implement-getstaticpaths); we are essentially required to tell next.js at build time which paths should be available for that particular page, like so:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const paths = getAllPostIds();
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

As shown [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#paths), we can return a `params` object with all available dynamic values instead of stringified paths:

```
return {
  paths: [
    { params: { id: '1' }},
    {
      params: { id: '2' },
      // with i18n configured the locale for the path can be returned as well
      locale: "en",
    },
  ],
  fallback: ...
}
```

**Question**

If I have a directory as the dynamic part and just a number of static pages in that directory, is there a way to avoid reimplementing `getStaticPaths()` in each and every page?

**Example**

```
  src/
    pages/
      users/
        [userId]/
          profile.tsx
          blog.tsx
          media.tsx
```

`profile.tsx`, `blog.tsx`, `media.tsx` all have the same code for `getStaticProps()`:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const userIds = getAllUserIds();
  return {
    paths: userIds.map(userId => ({
      params: {
        userId
      }
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

I would prefer a solution that resolves `userId` only once, maybe in `next.config.js`, in the router configuration or in an `index.tsx` file under `src/pages/users/[userId]`.

**Idea**

next.js uses a similar approach in `next-i18n` [called](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#sub-path-routing) "sub-path routing":

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en-US', 'fr', 'nl-NL'],
    defaultLocale: 'en-US',
  },
}
```

Here we tell next.js only once which locale identifiers should be allowed in a paths starting with `/[locale]/...`, and next.js will automagically resolve paths and pre-generate pages accordingly, per locale.

But as it seems this solution isn't generic and will only work for the first path segment.

Comment: You have to resolve the `userId` param on each page. You can abstract the logic into a reusable function to avoid code duplication, though.